# Cannot import QtCore in IDE but can in IDLE

Tags: python, import, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 on my computer, running Debian, and can import from it fine when using IDLE.

`>> from PyQt5 import QtCore`

However, if I include that same line of code in a .py script I get an error message.

`ImportError: cannot import name QtCore`

I am unsure about how to solve this problem.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you execute the .py?

Comment: I type ./test.py in my terminal

Comment: Do you use different python versions in IDLE and your python file? So which python interpreter is called, when you execute ./test.py? Can you try to execute test.py with the command `python test.py` and `python3 test.py`?

Comment: I did alias python='python3' so python3 would be my default python version but I still get the same error.